Как работать с кучей на языке ассемблера
Мне первый раз приходится работать с кучей так, что извините если написал ерунду.
Насколько я понимаю куча - это раздел оперативной памяти с которой может работать программа(Поправьте меня, если я не прав).
Есть два вида памяти с которыми может взаимодействовать программа - стек и куча(может быть есть и другие, но это все, про которые я слышал).
Если работа со стеком на языке ассемблера ясна, как день, то работа с кучей для меня - это большая загадка.
Помогите пожалуйста понять, как работать с кучей на языке ассемблера?

В Windows - GlobalAlloc и т.п., или https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/memory/heap-functions, если хотите быть чуть ближе к системе

Спасибо, @MBo, за объяснение

@MBo не возможно читать на русском, имхо

@Dmitry Да, ещё с артефактами перевода HeapDeкистрой ;)
